# Newbie jMock Q: Test method argument is any string that begins with a given prefix

Tags: java, jmockit, jmock

I have a mock object which expects that a method on it is called. How do I make sure that the string argument it expects begins with particular prefix?

```
oneOf(mockObject).methodName(with(any(String.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of JMockit, it provides the desired matcher out-of-the-box:

```
new Expectations() {{
    mockObject.methodName(withPrefix("PREFIX"));
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom matcher.  It turns out, the example on the jmock site on how to write a custom matcher covers writing one to match on prefixes.  I won't copy the code here, but the link is http://www.jmock.org/custom-matchers.html

Alternatively, a lazier approach would be to just check if the string contains the particular prefix anywhere in the string.  You can do that with the existing 'stringContaining' matcher.

```
oneOf(mockObject).methodName(with(stringContaining("PREFIX"));
```

Whether that's acceptable in your unit test though would depend on the string, the prefix, and what you're testing.